# turtlebot3 : Traffic Sign Detection Problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm following the steps of [Autonomous Driving](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/autonomous_driving/#autonomous-driving) and I've a problem with Traffic Sign Detection, when i launch this command:

`roslaunch turtlebot3_autorace_detect detect_sign.launch mission:=SELECT_MISSION`

(and i got it with all missions, intersection for example)

I got this error :

*----------------------------------------*

```
 roslaunch turtlebot3_autorace_detect detect_sign.launch mission:=intersection

... logging to /home/islam/.ros/log/c1a5f2be-e33d-11ec-94f8-af2ee1c316ed/roslaunch-islam-12287.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.42.0.1:40681/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14

NODES
  /
    detect_intersection_sign (turtlebot3_autorace_detect/detect_intersection_sign)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.1:11311

process[detect_intersection_sign-1]: started with pid [12301]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/islam/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_autorace_detect/detect_intersection_sign", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/islam/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_autorace_2020/turtlebot3_autorace_detect/nodes/detect_intersection_sign", line 246, in <module>
    node = DetectSign()
  File "/home/islam/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_autorace_2020/turtlebot3_autorace_detect/nodes/detect_intersection_sign", line 33, in __init__
    self.fnPreproc()
  File "/home/islam/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_autorace_2020/turtlebot3_autorace_detect/nodes/detect_intersection_sign", line 62, in fnPreproc
    self.sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT_create'
[detect_intersection_sign-1] process has died [pid 12301, exit code 1, cmd /home/islam/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_autorace_detect/detect_intersection_sign /detect/image_input:=/camera/image_compensated /detect/image_input/compressed:=/camera/image_compensated/compressed /detect/image_output:=/detect/image_traffic_sign /detect/image_output/compressed:=/detect/image_traffic_sign/compressed __name:=detect_intersection_sign __log:=/home/islam/.ros/log/c1a5f2be-e33d-11ec-94f8-af2ee1c316ed/detect_intersection_sign-1.log].
log file: /home/islam/.ros/log/c1a5f2be-e33d-11ec-94f8-af2ee1c316ed/detect_intersection_sign-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

*----------------------------------------*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401862/turtlebot3-:-traffic-sign-detection-problem/) by [BENBEY](https://answers.ros.org/users/104496/benbey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably installed `cv2` via `pip`, which does not contain any non-free modules.

This topic is discussed there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039224/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-xfeatures2d-python-opencv-2

People propose the use of:

> - Uninstall:
>
> `pip3 uninstall opencv-contrib-python`
>
> `pip3 uninstall opencv-python`
>
> - And then install:
>
> `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`
>
> `pip3 install opencv-python`

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BENBEY](https://answers.ros.org/users/104496/benbey/) on 2022-06-04**:
That solved it, Thank you